# uwsgi+gevent+django test concurrent request in thread asynchronously?

Tags: django, nginx

Recently, I ran a project with uwsgi abd gevent. But I found that gevent would create a new thread to execute the request instead of making it executed in the same thread.
Here is the simple test:[enter link description here](https://github.com/zebozhuang/mysite)

As we known, gevent is based on greenlet, so at least two functions will be executed in the same thread with gevent.spawn.

And uwsgi supports gevent, but it must create gevent queue with --gevent  option. It shows that every request is executed in different thread synchronously.

Now I want to know whether uwsgi and gevent with async mode can make requests executed in a single thread in one core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is to give you a reference. I've found R. De Ioris' work on gevent, greenlet and uwsgi to be excellent. He's on github and youtube:

https://github.com/rdeioris

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmdk5mVLsHM

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfkKOaNsE00

Also, the uwsgi irc (freenode, #uwsgi) is a great place to ask these type of questions.